# Les personnels et les syndicats

Tags: usage, pluriel

Je viens encore de rencontrer le nom *personnel*, qui pour moi et le [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/personnel) est un collectif, au pluriel dans la bouche d'un syndicaliste. [Le dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/personnel) a une remarque rappelant ce fait et signalant un cas où le pluriel est normal (*les personnels civil et militaire*).  L'exemple rencontré ne me semble pas relever de ce cas.

Est-ce que cet usage syndicaliste fait partie d'un jargon qui apporte une nuance non relevée par les dictionnaires que j'ai consultés ou est-ce qu'il s'agit simplement de l'habitude d'employer le pluriel dans les cas où il est justifié (donc pour désigner plusieurs catégories, même si elles ne sont pas explicite) qui déteint sur les cas où il n'est pas justifié?

Ajout de 2017. [Un exemple](http://snepap.fsu.fr/IMG/pdf/luynes_quand_les_gros_bonnets_bloquent_l_acces.pdf) dont voici les phrases pertinentes pour mon propos:

> [...] En quelques semaines, le Procureur de la
>   République, **un personnel** du greffe, du privé et plusieurs agents du SPIP se sont vus coincer à la porte [...]
>
> [...] Comment accepter que des **personnels** puissent être bloqués à la porte [...]

Dans les deux cas, *personnel* me semble être employé, une fois au singulier, une fois au pluriel, avec la signification *membre du personnel*.

Comment: Je ne vois pas (dans les deux sens du verbe) à quel exemple d'usage tu te réfères, et que tu places dans la bouche d'un syndicaliste. Mais peut-être que c'est moi qui suis fatiguée et ne vois pas les point sur les i.

Comment: @Laure, les syndicalistes utilisent souvent le nom _personnel_ au pluriel, tellement souvent que j'en suis à attendre cet usage quand ils passent à la radio et c'est rare que ce mot ne soit pas au pluriel quand ils l'utilisent. C'est un usage que je n'ai remarqué que dans leur bouche et celles de journalistes reprenant leurs propos.  Je me demande s'il a un sens particulier ou s'il ne s'agit que d'un tic.  Le dictionnaire de l'Académie donne un cas où il est justifié, mais il ne me semble pas recouvrir tous les cas que j'ai entendu.

Comment: Tu devrais citer un exemple parce que pour moi l'usage de personnel au pluriel me semble logique et normal pour se référer à plusieurs catégories de personnels. Par exemple [Les personnels enseignants de l'enseignement supérieur](http://www.education.gouv.fr/cid21784/les-personnels-enseignants-de-l-enseignement-superieur.html) parce que il y a plusieurs catégories professionnelles parmi le corps enseignant dans le supérieur. Par contre on parle du personnel de « cet hôtel qui est aux petits soins pour rendre votre séjour agréable » parce que ici le personnel de l'hôtel forme un seul ensemble.

Comment: Pour citer un exemple (et non en construire un), il va falloir que je tombe sur un (une recherche donne principalement sur des sites institutionnels qui ont un usage justifiable -- bien que dès qu'on n'explicite pas les catégories, j'ai l'impression qu'un singulier passerait mieux, l'effet semble être une distinction sans différence).

Comment: @Laure Le personnel enseignant d'un établissement supérieur se regroupe en personnel***s*** de l'enseignement supérieur représentant l'ensemble de l'élite de l'éducation nationale. Le personnel d'un établissement, les personnels d'un catégorie sociale.

Comment: Chez les militaires, _un personnel_ est simplement la version masculine d' _une personne_. Par exemple, une mine antipersonnel.

Comment: @Laure, je suis enfin tombé sur un exemple ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Les pluriels de type sont un usage standard des collectifs et des autres indénombrables. Si on achète trois marques différentes d'eau minérales, on revient avec trois eaux différentes bien que "eau" soit un [massif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre_grammatical#Noms_massifs.2C_noms_comptables.2C_noms_collectifs), d'où la mention "(d)es personnels civil et militaire" dans le TLF.

Parmi les catégories de personnel, il y les enseignants et les autres, au sein des enseignants, il existe également des différences : les personnels enseignants (professeurs, chargés de cours, assistants, vacataires, ...).

Comment: On est bien dans l'usage que je comprenais. J'ai maintenant cité un exemple de celui qui m'intrigue.

Answer (score 1):

Peut-être  les syndicalistes, surtout leurs chefs, emploient le mot «personnelS » au pluriel dans un sens non-collectif pour avoir un seul mot général et non-sexiste qui marche pour décrire tous les membres de leur « armée », soit une travailleuse ou un cadre ou une femme ou un homme.  Ca serait un peu comme les chefs militaires ici aux états-unis qui maintenant emploient le mot, auparavant collectif,  « troops » dans un nouveau sens non-collectif pour avoir un seul mot général et non-sexiste qui marche pour décrire tous les membres de toutes les branches militaires, soit un soldat ou un marine ou un homme ou une femme.

Comment: Votre réponse est difficile à lire, pouvez-vous l'améliorer SVP ? Cette réponse part dans de nombreuses directions très éloignées de la question. Je ne vois en quoi mentionner *troops * nous éclaire pour répondre à la question.

Comment: Merci @A.L vous avez raison.